# how to Import data from MYSQL to SQL Server with BLOB column?

Tags: mysql, sql-server

i'm exporting some rows from mysql to sql server with a CSV, but there is a BLOB column that I already tested exporting as base 64, hex but it is not imported correctly, the column type in SQL SERVER is varbinary (max).

How could I do it? What am I missing to do?

Thanks!

Comment: show what you are doing to export/import the rows, and explain what is not correct.

Comment: I am exporting from several IDEs, that BLOB column as base64, hex, binary, but when doing the import in any IDE such as DBEAVER for example, the record is inserted correctly, I know that it is wrong because when I download the content of that column with extension png It does not show the image, on the other hand with the records that are already in SQL Server it does show them, I think it is because the varbinary column does not accept base64, hex or binary natively.